# Python RAD (Desktop Deployment)

Tags: python

please forgive me if this questions were answered so many times!

How can I deploy desktop applications with python (in RAD way), I mean:
1. there is an IDE and i can create user interface(gui) like virtual studio that you just ***drag and drop objects*** (label, combobox, radiobutton...) to the form.

2.editing code behind that objects(label, combobox, radiobutton...) for example ***when i click a button with my mouse something happens***.

thanks in advance for answers. (forgive me for may English guys!)

Comment: Use one of the python GUI libraries, like tkinter.

Comment: I haven't used it, but Quickly might be worth a look:  http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/quickly/

Answer (score 2):

A good, non-free, IDE is [Wing](http://wingware.com/doc/howtos/pyqt)

If you don't want to pay for that, I suggest [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with the [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) plugin in combination with [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads). You'll need to use the `pyuic4` script that comes with PyQt to convert the `.ui` files from Qt Creator to python code, but it is a simple task.

Running this command will convert for you. 
`pyuic form1.ui > form1.py`