# Python RAD under Windows/Linux

Tags: python, ide

Héllo everybody, as this [question about RAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061639/python-rad-desktop-deployment) has been childishly closed 4 month ago without being answered and as [the only IDE question allowed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) isn't really up to date and doesn't fit my question (Visual Studio + PTVS + Wine to get a WPF only app under linux, no thanks) I will ask again:

Is there **at the moment** a viable python IDE with a simple GUI editor (**RAD** tool) ? (and possibly usable under Linux?)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Edited to remove the `rad` tag, as the `rad` tag is dedicated to Rational Application Developer.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Monkey Studio](http://monkeystudio.org/) (2012) a good IDE, RAD with GUI editor for QT4 with PyQT and it support python and other languages. Someone should add it to the python IDE list, unlock the topic or start a new topic up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, you can use (I use) a collection of separate tools. The pygtk package can use the Builder object to build a ui according to a scheme specified in an XML file. This XML file is generated by the glade UI builder tool.  I use Vim to edit the code. As you can see in your linked answer, that Vim has the highest voted answer as well.

However, I have extended the environment for myself with custom scripts and tools, often leveraging general purpose desktop tools and file managers. This is more aligned with the *nix philosophy of using the best tools (for you), working together. In other words, the whole *nix environment is an IDE, not a single application.

Otherwise, except for Vim, there is [Anjuta](http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/) that can create and develop Python/GTK projects.